# Assumptions for Univariate Analysis

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, t-test, feature-selection, fishers-exact-test

I am working a binary classification problem.

To identify the risk factors, I would first like to do `univariate analysis` and then do `multivariate analysis` based on the selected variables (from univariate analysis)

1)  What I would like to know is, I read online that for categorical variables, I should use `Fisher's exact test` and for continuous variables, I should use `Student t test`?

2)  Should I just use them or do I have verify the distribution of my data before I apply these two tests on my input variables. Because my sample size is more than 4k and less than 5K, so can I just use as is

3) In the univariate analysis, is there any other tests that I can apply for my categorical and continuous variables? Or it's always `Fishers` and `Student t test`

Comment: I know this wasn't asked, but I am going to highly recommend against univariable pre-filtering of the type you've mentioned.  See https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/tri.12895

Comment: regarding 3, discriminatory power (gini/AUC), regressing directly the variable.